# Definition of fork() in the program

Tags: unix, operating-system, system-calls

I have studied that fork() call creates a new process from where it is called in the program.

But in the following two programs, which are very similar, it shows different behavior.  Why is this?

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Start %d ", getpid()) ; 
    pid_t pid = fork() ;
    if (pid > 0)
        printf("Parent %d ", getpid()) ; 
    if (pid == 0)
        printf("Child %d ", getpid()) ;
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Output for this is:

```
Start 1104 Parent 1104 Start 1104 Child 1105
```

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Start %d \n", getpid()) ; 
    pid_t pid = fork() ;
    if (pid > 0)
        printf("Parent %d \n", getpid()) ; 
    if (pid == 0)
        printf("Child %d \n", getpid()) ;
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Output for this is:

```
Start 1126 
Child 1127 
Parent 1126
```

Just including "\n" changes the output.  What causes this?

Comment: By default "Standard Output" (stdout) is "line buffered" which means a newline flushes out any pending output.  Because the child process inherits the parent's I/O buffers, if there is anything in the buffers, they both have a copy of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use a stream in both the parent and the child, you need to flush it before you `fork`. Otherwise, whatever's left in the buffer will get flushed twice, once by the parent and once by the child.

Also, you should not return from `main` in both the parent and the child. If you do, any `atexit` handlers will run twice. This has caused bugs with security implications in the past. Either the parent or the child should either call `_exit` or successfully call one of the `exec` functions.